# upgrading brew doesn't work with any password - how to get proper permissions? - How should I manage brew properly?

Tags: macos, permissions, homebrew

As recommended, I created an admin user and a regular user which I use for regular usage.
for some reason I keep getting asked for my sudo admin password (when installing apps, updating apps, etc) - I was wondering if this is proper practice.

and to my main problem - brew isn't allowing me to update (`brew upgrade`) nor install whatever it suggests to install: `brew install --cask adoptopenjdk`

How can I get permissions for brew? (I tried Most of the suggested solutions)

- I tried using the regular user password and it just says that im not a sudoer.
- I tried using my other admin user password and it didn't work.
- I tried entering the other admin user via terminal using `su adminuser`+entering the admin password, then running `sudo chown -R myregularuser $(brew --prefix)/*`

this is my output.

```
myregularuser@my-MacBook-Pro ~ % brew upgrade
==> Casks with 'auto_updates' or 'version :latest' will not be upgraded; pass `--greedy` to upgrade them.
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package:
dbeaver-community 7.3.4 -> 7.3.5
==> Upgrading dbeaver-community
==> Caveats
dbeaver-community requires Java 8+. You can install the latest version with:
  brew install --cask adoptopenjdk

==> Downloading https://dbeaver.io/files/7.3.5/dbeaver-ce-7.3.5-macos.dmg
Already downloaded: /Users/myregularuser/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/b40befbe84ad7d63eb719fde242f0c4f7fb1a8d019f1b546db8595f6b1901ff1--dbeaver-ce-7.3.5-macos.dmg
==> Backing App 'DBeaver.app' up to '/usr/local/Caskroom/dbeaver-community/7.3.4/DBeaver.app'
Password:

myregularuser@my-MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
Password:
myregularuser is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

idk, maybe it's considered bad practice to use the regular user with brew, anyway, please help me to figure this out.

Edit:

I tried:

```
sudo chown -R myregularuser:admin /usr/local/Homebrew /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig /usr/local/share/aclocal /usr/local/share/doc /usr/local/share/info /usr/local/share/locale /usr/local/share/man /usr/local/share/man/man1 /usr/local/share/man/man3 /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7 /usr/local/share/man/man8 /usr/local/var/homebrew/locks

sudo chown -R myregularuser /usr/local/Homebrew /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig /usr/local/share/aclocal /usr/local/share/doc /usr/local/share/info /usr/local/share/locale /usr/local/share/man /usr/local/share/man/man1 /usr/local/share/man/man3 /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7 /usr/local/share/man/man8 /usr/local/var/homebrew/locks
```

both didn't work:

```
myregularuser@my-MacBook-Pro ~ % brew upgrade
==> Casks with 'auto_updates' or 'version :latest' will not be upgraded; pass `--greedy` to upgrade them.
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package:
dbeaver-community 7.3.4 -> 7.3.5
==> Upgrading dbeaver-community
==> Caveats
dbeaver-community requires Java 8+. You can install the latest version with:
  brew install --cask adoptopenjdk

==> Downloading https://dbeaver.io/files/7.3.5/dbeaver-ce-7.3.5-macos.dmg
Already downloaded: /Users/myregularuser/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/b40befbe84ad7d63eb719fde242f0c4f7fb1a8d019f1b546db8595f6b1901ff1--dbeaver-ce-7.3.5-macos.dmg
==> Backing App 'DBeaver.app' up to '/usr/local/Caskroom/dbeaver-community/7.3.4/DBeaver.app'
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
myregularuser is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
==> Purging files for version 7.3.5 of Cask dbeaver-community
Error: dbeaver-community: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/sudo -E -- /bin/cp -pR /Applications/DBeaver.app /usr/local/Caskroom/dbeaver-community/7.3.4/DBeaver.app` exited with 1. Here's the output:
myregularuser is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

the doctor says:

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Users/regularuser/.pyenv/shims/icu-config
  /Users/regularuser/.pyenv/shims/krb5-config
  /Users/regularuser/.pyenv/shims/libpng16-config
  /Users/regularuser/.pyenv/shims/python3.9-config
  /Users/regularuser/.pyenv/shims/python-config
  /Users/regularuser/.pyenv/shims/python3-config
  /Users/regularuser/.pyenv/shims/ncursesw6-config
  /Users/regularuser/.pyenv/shims/pcre-config
  /Users/regularuser/.pyenv/shims/python3.8-config
```

app permisions (notice dbeaver group)

```
regularuser@my-MacBook-Pro ~ % ls -la /Applications
total 0
drwxrwxr-x  49 root    admin  1568 Feb 20 21:47 .
drwxr-xr-x  20 root    wheel   640 Jan  1  2020 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root    wheel     0 Jan  1  2020 .localized
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root    wheel    96 Jan  2 23:14 AdBlock.app
lrwxr-xr-x   1 regularuser  admin    70 Jan  3 16:01 Anaconda-Navigator.app -> /Users/regularuser/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2020.07/Anaconda-Navigator.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 regularuser  staff    96 Dec 15 15:11 Bartender 4.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root    wheel    96 Jan 10 16:35 Battery Health 2.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root    wheel    96 Jan 30 17:32 BitdefenderVirusScanner.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root    wheel    96 Jan 23 06:27 Cinebench.app
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    wheel    96 Jan  4 23:12 Cubase 10.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 regularuser  staff    96 Feb 15 19:58 DBeaver.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 regularuser  admin    96 Dec 21 12:58 Docker.app
drwxr-xr-x   3 regularuser  admin    96 Feb 19 21:13 Dropbox.app
drwxr-xr-x   3 regularuser  admin    96 Jan  3 00:20 Fork.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 regularuser  staff    96 Dec 19 17:07 GIMP-2.10.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root    wheel    96 Jan 23 06:45 GPU Benchmark.app
drwxrwxr-x   3 regularuser  admin    96 Feb 13 05:43 Google Chrome.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root    wheel    96 Jan 26 21:34 Grammarly for Safari.app
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root    admin    43 Jan  4 21:56 HALion Library Manager.app -> /Applications/Steinberg Library Manager.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root    wheel    96 Jan 27 17:22 Instastats.app
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    wheel    96 Feb 19 20:53 IriunWebcam.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root    wheel    96 Jan  2 23:11 LastPass.app
drwxr-xr-x   3 regularuser  admin    96 Jan  4 21:56 License Control Center.app
drwxrwxr-x@  3 root    wheel    96 Feb 16 20:57 Microsoft Excel.app
drwxrwxr-x@  3 root    wheel    96 Feb 16 20:55 Microsoft PowerPoint.app
drwxrwxr-x@  3 root    wheel    96 Feb 16 20:56 Microsoft Word.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 regularuser  admin    96 Jan  9 02:07 OBS.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root    wheel    96 Feb 16 20:49 OneDrive.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root    wheel    96 Jan 30 18:26 Parcel.app
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    wheel    96 Feb  9 08:54 Postman.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root    wheel    96 Jan 21 16:10 Raindrop.io for Safari.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 regularuser  admin    96 Jan  6 11:38 Razer macOS.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root    wheel    96 Jan  1  2020 Safari.app
drwxr-xr-x   3 regularuser  staff    96 Dec  9 01:11 Spotify.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 regularuser  admin    96 Apr  7  2020 Steam.app
drwxr-xr-x   4 root    admin   128 Jan  4 21:55 Steinberg Download Assistant
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    wheel    96 Jan  4 21:56 Steinberg Library Manager.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 regularuser  admin    96 Oct  1  2019 Sublime Text.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 regularuser  admin    96 Dec 21 23:26 Turbo Boost Switcher.app
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    wheel    96 Jan  1  2020 Utilities
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    wheel    96 Feb  6 09:45 Visual Studio Code.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root    wheel    96 Feb 11 13:43 WhatsApp.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root    wheel    96 Feb  5 20:19 Xcode.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 regularuser  staff    96 Dec 16 11:41 gfxCardStatus.app
drwxr-xr-x   3 regularuser  staff    96 Feb 12 21:38 iTerm.app
drwxrwxrwx   3 root    admin    96 Jan 14 18:03 lghub.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 regularuser  staff    96 Jan 19 02:38 qBittorrent.app
drwxr-xr-x@  5 regularuser  admin   160 Nov  7 01:11 tbswitcher_resources
drwxr-xr-x   3 regularuser  wheel    96 Feb 11 14:45 zoom.us.app
```

a few new things i discovered:

I have been installing some apps on brew and everything works - BUT - it seems like some apps that use cask installations require sudo permissions (by the app, i think... doesn't have anything to do with brew itself) - I tried using `--app-dir=` (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/master/USAGE.md#options) on some, some worked and some didn't (wireshark didn't work but dbeaver worked) - and installed the app in a different folder I chose that isn't the `/Applications` folder. I tried selecting it, but nope, doesn't work.

`/Applications` is set to these permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x  48 root  admin  1536 Feb 20 22:07 Applications
```

I thought maybe something is wrong with my `/Applications` folder in terms of permissions. I cannot change its owner. I just wanted to mention that the regularuser I am currently using used to be a sudo user. when I discovered that when using the mac for regular stuff it's recommended to use a non-sudo user - I decided to create a new user to be the sudo user, and remove the sudo from the regularuser. I don't know if it has something to do with it.

Comment: You don't have to enter `sudo` again and again; start a _root-session_ with command `sudo bash`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond `sudo bash` asks for a password where non of them work (both passwords of the regularuser and sudo user...)

Comment: If you can become root (anyhow), then you can add your regular user into your `/etc/sudoers` file. (sg like this: `username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`).

Answer (score 0):

Just give your myregularuser a sudo privilege just for this installation

**First Step :** Enter your user admin

```
su adminuser
```

**Second Step :** Give myregularuser the sudo privilege

```
sudo adduser myregularuser sudo
```

**Finaly :** Now you can install something that you couldn't install before in regular user

**Last Step :** After everything is finished, remove the sudo privilege from myregularuser, so the regularuser will return to its original function

```
sudo deluser myregularuser sudo
```

Comment: so, i should add and remove my regularuser everytime i install a problomatic app with brew cask? isnt there any other comfortable way doint that?

Comment: Still have to use this way I think, because myregularuser is not in the sudoers file.